# ddply() doesn't appear to subset within my data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I trying to obtain summary statistics within subsets of my dataset and naturally turned to the plyr package and since I'm working with a data frame ddply().  I can't see why this doesn't work though....

```
t <- as.data.frame(cbind(1, seq(1:20)))
t2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(2, seq(21:40)))
t <- rbind(t, t2)
rm(t2)
is.data.frame(t)
[1] TRUE
ddply(t, .(V1), function(x) c(missing = sum(is.na(t$V2)),
                              n       = sum(!is.na(t$V2)),
                              mean    = mean(t$V2, na.rm = TRUE),
                              sd      = sd(t$V2, na.rm = TRUE)))
  V1 missing  n mean      sd
1  1       0 40 10.5 5.83974
2  2       0 40 10.5 5.83974
```

I've read a few things like [this quick overview](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2009/08/a-fast-intro-to-plyr-for-r/) and some threads here on Stackoverflow having searched and found similar questions, and thought I'd got it right, but clearly not.  Any insight as to what I've done wrong or misunderstood would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance,

slackline

Comment: Everything inside the function should be in terms of `x`, its argument. Currently, you are reaching back into the global environment and calculating the values on the whole data frame, `t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a couple problems. First, don't use `seq` in conjunction with the colon operator. Using a colon alone will get you the sequence you need:

```
1:20
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21:40
# [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
```

If you use both, `seq` will give you a sequence *along* the sequence you pass it:

```
seq(21:40)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Second, `t` is your entire dataset. You want to operate on `x`, the subset defined by `V1`:

```
ddply(t, .(V1), function(x) c(missing = sum(is.na(x$V2)),
                              n       = sum(!is.na(x$V2)),
                              mean    = mean(x$V2, na.rm = TRUE),
                              sd      = sd(x$V2, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: If we're dispensing advice, `as.data.frame(cbind())` is also something that should generally be avoided.

Comment: The generation of the two column data frame was purely to post a reproducible example, but I now see the error of my ways in that regard as I ended up with exactly the same set of numbers! Foolish, but a good lesson learnt.  What would be recommended instead of 'as.data.frame(cbind())' joran?

Comment: Thank you both for pointing out the now obvious error I've made with regards to what should be operated on.  Still struggling with functions, but should now hopefully remember this in the future.

Comment: @slackline (1) It's actually shorter to just type `data.frame(V1 = rep(1,20),...)` and (2) if not all your data are numeric, `cbind` will convert everything to characters.

Comment: @slackline, in your `ddply` call, you may also replace `function(x)` with `summarize,`. Then you can remove the `c( )` and `x$`

Comment: @Henrik : Thanks for the tip.  In my real-world situation I've a call to `centile` with `probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)` that prevented it from working correctly, but have now split that into three separate calls and it works fine, certainly less typing this way.

Comment: @juran ah, converting everything to strings could be problematic, thanks for the insight.